# How to create PS file from PDF file using Java?

Tags: java, operating-system, adobe, postscript

I wrote an application to create **PDF** file to **PDDocument** file  it work fine. i use the pdfbox library

```
PDDocument pdfDoc = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);
```

Now i want to create **PS**(Post script) file from **PDF** file. Is there are any way in java. I can use any free API.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe seems to have a library. Here are some instructions. Please note, I have not tried this myself: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/programLC/help/index.htm?content=000761.html

This link has a more detailed solution:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/programLC/help/index.htm?content=000074.html

Comment: Adobe LiveCycle is not free (or even open). You could use Ghostscript, but I have no idea how to do that from Java.

Comment: Simple Google search found this: http://www.ghost4j.org/. It's described as "Ghost4J binds the Ghostscript C API to bring Ghostscript power to the Java world. It also provides a high-level API to handle PDF and Postscript documents with." Sorry I didn't realize the Adobe library wasn't free. To be honest I didn't find a whole lot on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PDFDocument to load your **PDF** then use PSConverter to convert the PDF document into an OutputStream.

The library I'm using is called [ghost4j](http://www.ghost4j.org/):

```
import org.ghost4j.converter.PSConverter; 
import org.ghost4j.document.PDFDocument;
```

Here's a small snippet:

```
private ByteArrayOutputStream convertPDFtoPS(){

    ByteArrayOutputStream  outstreamFile = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try{            
        PDFDocument document = new PDFDocument();
        //getPDFFile just returns an InputStream of the PDF file
        document.load(getPDFFile());           
        PSConverter converter = new PSConverter();
        converter.convert(document, outstreamFile); 

        outstreamFile.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return outstreamFile;    
}
```